# is it advisable to use inline CSS styles for twbootstrap elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i would like to know if it's good practice to use inline CSS styles to manipulate bootstrap elements:

for example:

```
<img src="swim-2.jpg" height="400" width="400" alt="swimmingClass" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="margin-top:10%;transform:rotate(-10deg);">
```

but i have a few images and div blocks where i use inline styles to change padding and position. is it bad coding practice?

Comment: Are you doing this for specificity reasons?

Comment: This is an opinion based question, you should re-word it.

Comment: @sma i am trying to align elements to my liking. but while doing so i do not want to divert too far from industry standards on good coding practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Avoid using inline styles.*

Create a new file `custom.css`. Refer/Load it after Bootstrap.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/custom.css">
```

Add a custom class to the element.

**HTML**

```
<img src="swim-2.jpg" height="400" width="400" alt="swimmingClass" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive transform">
```

**CSS**

```
/* custom.css */
.transform {
  margin-top: 10%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really use inline styling. It will be a pain if you ever have to change any of it. If you use that style on each image you would have to update each image to match. The point of CSS is to separate the presentation from the structure, using a custom css file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should really never use inline-styling. The HTML is not a "do'er" it is just "idle". So you trying to make HTML do things like styles etc would not really be the most effective coding. Besides that it just looks plain messy.